# 2nd day Yom Tov for chutznikim in Israel. Locate the law and reasons of the Shulchan Oruch Horav

Tags: sources-mekorot, yom-tov, baal-hatanya

I am researching the laws of the second day of Yom Tov in Golus. 
On one occasion, I found the text of the Shulchan Oruch Horav Orach Chaim 496 which states that someone not from Israel who is visiting Israel need keep only one day.

Together with this, I found text which suggested a reason for this relating to the emanation of the Yom Tov which in golus expands into two days.

Now I cannot find these texts.

Where online are the texts to which I refer?

Comment: This is also the position of the Chacham Tzvi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are searching for is [Shulchan Aruch HaRav, Orach Chaim, volume 4, siman 496, seif 11 and notes 45-46](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25075&st=&pgnum=32), together with their back reference to [note 25 for seif 7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25075&st=&pgnum=31).

As requested, links to both locations have been provided.

Comment: Thank you for the ref. to the Sh O Horav. For the point on emanations I found http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/יום_טוב_שני_של_גלויות#.D7.94.D7.A1.D7.91.D7.A8_.D7.94.D7.97.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.93.D7.95.D7.AA to give the point.